# How to put an image in div with CSS?

Tags: css, image

I would like to have all my images in CSS (the only way I know how is to put them in as background images).

But the problem in this solution is you can never let the div take the size of the image.

So my question is: what is the best way to have the equivalent of 
`<div><img src="..." /></div>` in CSS?

Comment: Backgrounds are not an alternative: backgrounds have to be used if images are not relevant for the content comprehension, otherwise they should be as regular `<img>`

Comment: Other than manually finding out the size of the image and giving the div the same, I don't think you can.

Comment: The right way: `<img>` if image is relevant, `<div>` with background if image is eye-candy only. If image size is variable and important, you should use `<img>`. Why do you want to use background?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

This answer by [Jaap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1227949/jaap) :

```
<div class="image"></div>​
```

and in CSS :

```
div.image::before {
   content:url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
}​
```

you can try it on this link :
http://jsfiddle.net/XAh2d/

this is a link about css content
http://css-tricks.com/css-content/

This has been tested on Chrome, firefox and Safari. (I'm on a mac, so if someone has the result on IE, tell me to add it)

Comment: This does not make `div` taking the same size of the image, as you asked. Look what happen if you add a border to div: http://jsfiddle.net/XAh2d/6/ Nothing, because the div has size 0x0 and is hidden behind image.

Comment: you should remove the :before, i edited my answer. check it here http://jsfiddle.net/2pFhc/

Comment: Now, be sure `url` content is supported by all browsers. As w3schools says: *IE8 only supports the content property if a !DOCTYPE is specified.*

Comment: @dyyyy yeah, that was me... I think it was deleted after Alessandro and I started looking for a solution for the size of the container div.

Comment: @DanyY hey, you said you updated your fiddle, but I see only green borders there: http://jsfiddle.net/2pFhc/ why?

Comment: Note that [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content) should be used with pseudo (before or after) elements only, so while it works with Chrome or Firefox, it does NOT with IE <= 9.

Comment: A problem I dealt with for years.  thank you for the awesome solution!

Comment: This did not work for me on firefox 55. Need some crossbrowser decision. Works with before|after.

Comment: works for me on FF and chrome with ::before and display: flex; => http://jsfiddle.net/q0vL1m7v/1/

Comment: Yes, that's true but how can I use local path in identity>pages>Account>login.cshtml      `In Asp.net Core & React JS Project`

Comment: On React JS the link needs to be a string

Answer (score 28):

you can do this:

```
<div class="picture1">&nbsp;</div>
```

and put this into your css file:

```
div.picture1 {
   width:100px; /*width of your image*/
   height:100px; /*height of your image*/
   background-image:url('yourimage.file');
   margin:0; /* If you want no margin */
   padding:0; /*if your want to padding */
}
```

otherwise, just use them as plain

Comment: I was trying to avoid fixed sizes.

Comment: If you are trying to avoid fixed sizes, then the easiest way is to use the plain `img` tag. What are you trying to accomplish with this? Maybe there's another solution programatically, like getting the image size via PHP getimagesize and then echo a corresponding `style` and or `img` tag for that certain image.

Answer (score 5):

Take this as a sample code. Replace imageheight and image width with your image dimensions.

```
<div style="background:yourimage.jpg no-repeat;height:imageheight px;width:imagewidth px">
</div>
```

Comment: Works but question was regarding "CSS"

Comment: Perhaps it shouldn't.

Answer (score 5):

With Javascript/Jquery:

- load image with hidden `img`
- when image has been loaded, get width and height
- dynamically create a `div` and set width, height and background
- remove the original `img`

  ```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var image = $("<img>");
      var div = $("<div>")
      image.load(function() {
        div.css({
          "width": this.width,
          "height": this.height,
          "background-image": "url(" + this.src + ")"
        });
        $("#container").append(div);
      });
      image.attr("src", "test0.png");
    });
  ```