# Hide the src image in an <img> element, but show its background image

Tags: css

I have an image element, to which I've added a different background image using CSS.

```css
img {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eiS4.png') !important;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/smHPA.png" />
```

I want to show the CSS-specified background image ([the Stack Exchange logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eiS4.png)) in the image element, instead of the image specified by the `src` attribute ([the Stack Overflow logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smHPA.png)).

Is this possible? I have a situation where I can't alter the HTML or use JavaScript, and am looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 32):

[The `object-position` CSS property](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#the-object-position), which is supported by both Chrome and Firefox, provides a fairly direct solution to this problem. This property is used to offset the rendering position of the native image within its element. The specification helpfully notes that...

> Areas of the box not covered by the replaced element will show the element’s background.

...so as long as we provide an offset which ensures the native image will be entirely out-of-bounds, the background will be visible instead. For example:

```css
img {
  object-position: -99999px 99999px;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eiS4.png');
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/smHPA.png" />
```

Comment: Also supported by Opera (prefixed from v11.6 to v19), not supported by IE or Safari.

Answer (score 31):

I found a solution that works in all major browsers (tested in IE8+) trying with brute force.

```css
img {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eiS4.png') !important;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 32px;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 32px 36px 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/smHPA.png"/>
```

It has some tricks. You have to give actual width and height of the image as width and height. Then set the padding left and top to that width and height respectively. I don't know if overflow is relevant but just added it. Box-sizing must be border-box.

Edit: Solution is more minimal. One of `padding-left` or `padding-top` is enough and there is no need for `overflow:hidden`. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmLyz38e/1/) with it.

Comment: I'd suggest specifying the `height` & `width` attributes directly in the  `img` tag. This would require adding `overflow:hidden` again. Also, in case the image used for the background is smaller than the actual image, it might be an idea to set the `background-position` and `background-repeat` properties.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't possible in every browser, but in WebKit and Blink browsers (such as Safari and Chrome) it can be accomplished by using the `content` property to replace the `src`-specified image content of an `<img>` element. Using `content: none` to entirely remove it doesn't seem to work, but we can replace it with a transparent GIF to achieve the same effect.

This will change the intrinsic dimensions of the image (to 1x1 in this case), so you'll also need to add an explicitly `width` and `height` if they weren't already specified.

```css
img {
  content: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==');
  width: 32px;
  height: 36px;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eiS4.png');
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/smHPA.png" />
```

Comment: @lrtad I remember reading somewhere that the `content` property is only valid for the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, according to the CSS3 specs.

Answer (score 1):

**This should work**

You image is here

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/smHPA.png" />
```

let's say its **height is 100px** and **width is 200px**

then your css stylesheet should be like this one

```
img{
    display: block;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    padding-left:200px;
    background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eiS4.png') no-repeat;
   }
```

basically what you have to do, just insert **border-box** property first and then **provide left padding equal to width of the image**

Answer (score 0):

make sure the "content" img is the same size as the `img` you're covering up. This works better than using background-images to cover foreground images.

```
div.image:before {
  position:absolute;
   content:url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
}
```

credit this post from a few years back https://stackoverflow.com/a/10833692/3247527

Answer (score 0):

You can displace the image and add class to the image to give it background.

```
img {
    position:relative;
    left:-99999px;
}
.background{
    width : 300px;
    height : 300px;
    background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/255379/pexels-photo-255379.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    left:0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use images. Use `div`'s with a background image

`<img>` is an HTML tag. CSS is there to add style to it, not to change the attributes of it. Below mentioned is a workaround. I wouldn't recommend it though. Not a very clean approach.

Sample Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .style2{background:url('bg.jpg') 0 0 repeat !important;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background:url(img.png) 0 0; width:728px; height:90px;" class="style2" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that 4 leading spaces make your text to be formatted as code. Remove them for your text to be shown as text and not formatted as HTML source.

Answer (score -1):

You can't change HTML but you can **replace the image** ! 
Open Photoshop and make a 100% transparent image with same name as source and put it in the same directory where current image is.

What will happen here ? Image tag will occupy the space as the size of transparent image and background image will be visible :)