# How to add checkmarks and x's when validating in angularjs?

Tags: css, angularjs

I couldn't find anything in the angularjs docs, nor online, about this specific aspect of form validation. You know when someone writes something in an input field (example: name, phone number, email etc.), and then there is a green checkmark that appears? Or an X that appears implying it's wrong, incomplete etc.

So, I have those images in my folder and ready for use in either situation. Problem is, I can't find the documentation to properly achieve what I would like to achieve. I am thinking that angularjs would be the solution to use, as the rest of my code in is angular.

Since this is angularjs, the only post and documentation that presented a viable option (which does not work for a few reasons) are the following options:

[How to put an image in div with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829675/how-to-put-an-image-in-div-with-css)

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

I was thinking of using CSS to trick the browser into making the one or the other image appear as it validates. I thought it might force the image in my **other** div to appear, but to no avail.

**For example, in this CSS, I tried this:**

```
.ng-valid.ng-dirty .div.test{
    border-color: green;
    content:url(http://example.com/image);
    }
```

**Using this in my HTML:**

```
<div class="test">
               <label style="float:left">by:</label>
               <input class="form-control controltwo" required ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.author" name="email" id="email" type="email" style="width:350px;" placeholder="Email Address"/>

</div>
```

As I said before, I am trying to achieve something using angularjs. As CSS can be used for styling, it cannot be tricked into being a styling option and a complex validator. I've tried a few tricks as show on the links, but they don't work. As for the second link, it just isn't made for this purpose, and considering they are made only for filters and images, the docs for the filters don't help a bit.

Comment: Can we see some more code? Are you using forms? If you are, you can utilise the $invalid properties of the form or form controls

Comment: Many possible answers to this - depends on how fancy you want to get.

Comment: @link64, Here's a plunker. This should contain all appropriate info. And yes, I use a form. http://embed.plnkr.co/gftAajibCbNphhgRy0nx/preview

Comment: @pixelbits Not fancy lol, just being able to use the small pics I have whenever an email seems right or wrong as the person is typing and so on... is all I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way of achieving what you want is to look in to the $valid or $invalid properties of your form control.

For example, to show a small message when the email is invalid, you would put this element in your markup.

```
<div ng-show='reviewForm.email.$dirty && reviewForm.email.$invalid'>Invalid Email</div>
```

Where `reviewForm` is the name of your form, and `email` is the name of your input control.

Here is a plunkr demonstrating this: http://plnkr.co/edit/tUuToy99xjfMhbyMd3eV

You can replace the element with whatever else you want

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly it. Not fancy, but simple as I was looking for. May look for fancy stuff in the future lol, or use a gif instead. Kudos to you. I would up your answer, but I only have 14 reps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `ng-show`, `ng-src` and `ng-model` depending on what you're validating.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

The example under ng-model:text shows pretty much what you want. If you're not using forms, you should be able to use `ng-change` to fire off a check and change the image to the appropriate one.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D

If `ng-show` watches the $valid attribute of the field in question you can hide the check mark when validation is false, and show it when true. You can flip the logic if you want an X.

Comment: For now, I tested Link's (the person lol, not a link). I will check all the links and verify if there could be a more viable solution. Thank you for the links. I had a hard time formulating a question via google and even via stackoverflow. So having some references to verify will help.

Comment: I can now give you a +1 :)