# How to assign heart icon to beats per minute counter javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To start of, I would like to notify that I am pretty new to javascript, I hope you will bear with me.

I have this code that on mouse down it counts the beats per minute.  What I would like to do is display a Heart Icon in the space of the division so that when someone clicks the heart it will display the BPM.

This is what I have now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tapDiv" style="height:200px;width:200px;background-color:#000;color:#FFF"></div>

    <script>

        lastTapSeconds = 0;
        bpm = 0;

        var tapDiv = document.getElementById("tapDiv");

        function bpmCounter() { 

            var tapSeconds = new Date().getTime();

            bpm = ((1 / ((tapSeconds - lastTapSeconds) / 1000)) * 60);
            lastTapSeconds = tapSeconds;            
            tapDiv.innerHTML = "<h1>" + Math.floor(bpm) + "</h1>";  
        }

        tapDiv.onmousedown = bpmCounter;

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

How do I implement a heart icon (image) so that it will display that and interact with the js?

I though perhaps I could enter a source in the division and direct to the heart.png in my directory so that it will display that and work with the tapDiv id. But I am not sure of this.

I hope I have given you enough info.

thanks

Mieer

Comment: [This codepen](http://codepen.io/jakealbaugh/full/PwLXXP/) knows

Comment: Look up the IMG tag. And this isn't really a question that'll help anyone else one day, thus off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Simple Way:**

Replace:

```
tapDiv.innerHTML = "<h1>" + Math.floor(bpm) + "</h1>";
```

with:

```
tapDiv.innerHTML = '<h1 style="display:inline">' + Math.floor(bpm) + '</h1><img src="/Images/heart.png"/>';  
//specify your own source path for heart.png
```

this simply adds an image element to your dynamically created content and is probably the easiest to implement with your current code set:
[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/nzdrd1h4/)

**Alternate Way:**

You can use CSS to set an image by specifying a class, and this is the more preferred method: [how to put an image in div with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829675/how-to-put-an-image-in-div-with-css)

Comment: Hi there, I did:    tapDiv.innerHTML = '<h1>' + Math.floor(bpm) + '</h1><img src="'heart.ico'"/>; but it doesn't do anything when clicked.

Comment: I added a fiddle and I put an inline style on h1 so they would be on the same line.  The fiddle works as intended, I believe.  Based on your code in your comment, you are missing a closing single quote (') after />