# Why is CSS content image not displaying?

Tags: html, css

Consider this html:

```
<div class="logo-b"></div>
```

And this CSS:

```
div.logo-b {
    content: url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid darkred;
}
```

I am trying to display an image using CSS. The image is not being displayed.  Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Iamnota12345/20tenm6a/) to see what I mean.  What am I missing please?

EDIT: It appears that Chrome renders the fiddle as I provided it above fine, but Firefox (which I use) does not.  If I add `:before` or `:after` to the class name in my CSS the image displays in Firefox.  Could someone shed some light on why this would be please?

EDIT: I am using the wrong construct to place the image on my page.  In the context of what I am doing I should use the `<img>` html tag.  The CSS `content` construct uses `:before` and/or `after` to place content, including images, but I understand these are used in specific contexts. I simply want to display a logo.

Comment: The fiddle works for me

Comment: Yeah this fiddle forks fine

Comment: `content:'';` without `:before` or `:after` o_0 i think you should use `background-image`

Comment: Wow. The border displays fine, but the image does not display

Comment: I have a little old mozilla, in that, this fiddle does not works until I add `:after` or `:before` pseudo class, I don't know whether the fiddle will work without those psuedo classes or not?

Comment: Oh! So, when I add `:before` or `:after` to the class name in the CSS the image displays.  Does anyone know why I need to add :before or :after to the CSS class please?

Comment: first i don't know why the fiddle you provided works for vaultah and Zafer Ayan ??????

Comment: I think Chrome manipulates this CSS, and works properly.

Comment: Right - the fiddle works in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Hmm. I have no idea what's happening here.

Comment: so in general we must use `:before` or `:after` always.. problem solved in comments ;)

Comment: also works on chromium; could it be a clearfix issue?

Comment: @maioman - it does not appear to be the case.  I have added a clearfix fix to the fiddle and it has no apparent effect on the result - the image still does not display in Firefox

Comment: @SteveCooke you're right, it has nothing to do with clearfix: the reason is that by definition the content property is used with the :before and :after pseudo-elements, to insert generated content. (that's why FF doesn't support it.. but chrome does :)

Comment: @maioman - thank you.  It appears I should not be using `content` to add an image with CSS, at least not for the reason I am displaying the image.  Maybe when using an image, say, with a message to indicate a warning.

Comment: a 'more' common way to insert image through CSS would be through `background` property

Comment: Yes - but I am aware of this: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829675/how-to-put-an-image-in-div-with-css#comment14098568_10829675)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This property `content` is used with the `:before` and `:after`
>   pseudo-elements to generate content in a document. -[W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content)

I think the behavior in Firefox is correct.

Comment: Yes - as per the comments under my question, this is the correct answer.  I don't know it provides a complete understanding of my problem - more on that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829675/how-to-put-an-image-in-div-with-css#comment14098716_10829675)

Comment: I don't know what your other question is, can you clarify it? or post a new question if it's not quite relevant to the same one.