# How can I add pictures to my web via CSS

Tags: html, css

Well, im a little new on html and CSS I want to put some pictures on my web, and I want to do it via CSS, my question is how can I do that

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)? Can't tell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put an image in div with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829675/how-to-put-an-image-in-div-with-css)

Comment: just google it, you will find. Look at w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert into your CSS this to load the image

```
div.picture {
   content:url(the_url_of_the_image_or_route);
}
```

Use this to show your image:

```
<div class="picture"></div>
```

Hope you understand :D

Answer (score 2):

The question is a little vague, but lets supose that you're talking about a background image for your website...

Than you would set in your .css file something like this:

```
body {
    background-image: img/myImage.jpg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to understand how css can help you with your website I suggest you check this out:  http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a background image to cover the whole page and stretch to fill the entire screen here is something you can do. The url for the image should be the path were the image is located. If you don't have an images folder and the image is located in the same place as your html file then for the url use url(bg.jpg) or whatever your image is called. Please be more clear on exactly how you want to add an image on your webpage. Also providing the source code you currently have would be a major help. You might have a minor syntax error.

```
 <style type="text/css">
      html { 
             background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
             -webkit-background-size: cover;
             -moz-background-size: cover;
             -o-background-size: cover;
             background-size: cover;
           }
 </style>
```

Or if you want to just add an image to your website you can use the image tag inside the body. Here is an example. make sure the image you are including is located in the same folder as your hmtl file. Otherwise specify the path in the src.

```
<img id="image3" src"bg.jpg" />
```

After creating the html image tag then you can reference the id for that specific image in your css file if you have on or in the `<style>` tags.

```
 #image3{
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
 }
```

You can do a lot more to an image with css, I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do.