# How to display images in JSP file, which are in different folders, as shown below?

Tags: java, image, jsp

How to display images (present in `assets/img/plus.png`) in `temp.jsp` file (present in `jsp` folder)? Shown in image:

[image]

Comment: Do you want the JSP just to serve a reference to the image via <img> HTML tag or do you want the JSP to be the image itself when requested by the client?

Comment: via <img> HTML tag. jsp's and images are in different folders.

Comment: <img alt="" src="assets/img/minus.png">, when I click on this link (in view source) , it is redirecting to 'http://localhost:8084/JavaSampleProject/jsp/assets/img/minus.png' and image is not displaying

Answer (score 0):

JSP understands usual HTML. So you can do it the same way.

Using `<img>` tag: [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp).

Or css: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829675/how-to-put-an-image-in-div-with-css).

If you are not sure about how to get images from another folder: read it [here](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/).

Answer (score 0):

you just call the `<img src='../image/image_name.extension'/>`
../ this used for back on one folder only