# Displaying Bootstrap Icon before text with CSS shows code instead icon

Tags: html, css, blockquote

I need to display the bootstrap Glyphicons before the element in which the `.normal-text` class has been used: I am trying with the following but it shows the code instead the icon.

```css
.normal-text{
   border-left-width: 1px !important;
   font-size: 110% !important;
   color: #100cce;
   font-family: 'Book Antiqua';
}
.normal-text::after{
   content: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>'
}
```

```html
<blockquote class="normal-text"> Some Text </blockquote>
```

Help required in this please.

Comment: The glypicon should be before the element, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use unicode instead. `content:''` will treat code block as a text.

```css
.normal-text{
   border-left-width: 1px !important;
   font-size: 110% !important;
   color: #100cce;
   font-family: 'Book Antiqua';
}
.normal-text::after{
   content: "\270f";
   font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<blockquote class="normal-text"> Some Text </blockquote>
```

Comment: thats great, but what if i need to put an html image instead icon code?

Comment: you can write like this `<img src="your_image_path" alt="..." >` make sure you give css to img tage as `display-inline-block` to be appeared in the same line.

Comment: @AbdulRahman this post [how-to-put-an-image-in-div-with-css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829675/how-to-put-an-image-in-div-with-css) will help you.

Comment: ok great, thanks i have gone through with...it works fine now.

Comment: THANK YOU! 
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings'; this is the line that was missing for me!

Answer (score 3):

You can not display icon like that. You should used icon unicode with it's font family.

```css
.normal-text{
   border-left-width: 1px !important;
   font-size: 110% !important;
   color: #100cce;
   font-family: 'Book Antiqua';
}
.normal-text::after{
   content: "\270f";
   font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<blockquote class="normal-text"> Some Text </blockquote>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't include `span tag` into CSS `content property`.

> The content CSS property is used with the ::before and ::after
>   pseudo-elements to generate content in an element.

```css
.normal-text{
border-left-width: 1px !important;
font-size: 110% !important;
color: #100cce;
font-family: 'Book Antiqua';
}
.normal-text::after{
 content: ' \00270e '
}
```

```html
<blockquote class="normal-text"> Some Text </blockquote>
```

Answer (score 2):

**I think it will help you.**

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),            url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), 
       url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}

.glyphicon:before {
  content: "\e008";
  padding-right:10px;
  font-size:24px;
  float:left;
}
.glyphicon > p {
  float:left;
  font-size:24px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span class="glyphicon"><p>User</p></span>
```

Comment: this is an awesome code, i am going to use this code because it has the required fonts for icons. that's great...

Answer (score 1):

i think it will help you. make html as given below and no need to after css

```
<blockquote class="normal-text"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Some Text </blockquote>
```

check this link : https://jsfiddle.net/vt3d7pLv/

Comment: yap you are right but i have little different scenario, that's why i am going to use like that... anyways, thanks it has been answered.

Comment: so you can go with this css 
.normal-text::after{
   content: "\270f";
   font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Bootstrap 5 it should be like this:

```
.normal-text::after {
  content: '\F12A';
  font-family: "bootstrap-icons";
}
```

Use the CSS code in the icon detail page as the content.