# bootstrap 5 icons and pseudo elements

Tags: bootstrap-5

I think when bootstrap was using Glyphicons, you could change your font to Glyphicons Halflings and then use the ::before pseudo element to display a unicode character before every list item. A unicode character that looked a little better than the default, like the pencil for example.

[See this StackOverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44016539/111665)

Q: Can you use bootstrap 5's icons with css pseudo elements? Maybe Glyphicons is open source and so I could download it separately from bootstrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, here is the example for **Caret right fill** icon:

```
::before {
    content: "\F231";
    font-family: "Bootstrap-icons";
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```css
li::before {
   content: "\F7CB";
   font-family: "Bootstrap-icons";
   padding-inline-end: .5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
</ul>
```