# How to create, refer to the image using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

I just want a simple css and HTML to fix this issue.

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829675/how-to-put-an-image-in-div-with-css

Comment: A simple way to do it could be like this -- https://jsfiddle.net/4yo1qhpf/5/

Comment: *to fix this issue* - what issue?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help,

```css
.heading{
  display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 0px;
}
.heading h2{
  font-size: 25px;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
}

.heading:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <h2>Function</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 0px;
}
.wrapper h2{
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 30px;
    margin: auto;
}

.wrapper:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    background: #999;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1px; /*this will keep this line vertically center to heading text*/
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Functions</h2>
</div>
```