# How to place an image on top of text div and make the height responsive according to the text box height

Tags: css, sass, positioning

I am a starting web developer and in need of help making image box responsive.

What I am aiming for is this
[Image Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLNba.png)

Right now my current html looks like

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content-box">
    <div class="img-box">
      <img class="" src="" alt="">
    </div>
  
    <div class="text-box">
      <h1 class="">Header 1</h1>
      <p>Header 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And css looks like

```
.container {
  .content-box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;

    .img-box {
      width: 55%;
      position: absolute;
      
      img {
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 594px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
    }

    .text-box {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 3rem;
      padding: 8rem;
      width: 45%;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the image is not responsive from the text box's height.
It is supposed to always stick out from top and bottom but when the text box gets big, the image goes inside the text box.

I was wondering what will be the ideal way to make it responsive?

Comment: Read this： https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829675/how-to-put-an-image-in-div-with-css

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going the: `flex`, you could simply `position: absolute` the image container.

The `.content-box` should be `position: relative` to allow the image to be `positioned: absolute`.

Your `.text-box` will have a `padding-right` equal to the `width` of the image plus the wanted `padding` on the left and on the right of the image.

```css
:root {
  --text-width: 50%;
  --text-padding: 3rem;
}

.container {
  padding: var(--text-padding) 0;
}

.content-box {
  position: relative;
}

.text-box {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: var(--text-padding);
  padding-right: calc(100% - var(--text-width) - var(--text-padding));
}

.img-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--text-padding) * -1);
  bottom: calc(var(--text-padding) * -1);
  right: var(--text-padding);
  width: calc(var(--text-width) - var(--text-padding) * 3);
}

.img-box img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/* for the sake of the presentation */
.container + .container {
  margin-top: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content-box">
    <div class="img-box">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/400" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="text-box">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur nam officia, fugit laboriosam enim corporis beatae sunt, quo ex blanditiis, iusto voluptate quos? Vitae, ad quas distinctio asperiores quaerat atque?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="content-box">
    <div class="img-box">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/400" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="text-box">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur nam officia, fugit laboriosam enim corporis beatae sunt, quo ex blanditiis, iusto voluptate quos? Vitae, ad quas distinctio asperiores quaerat atque?
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur nam officia, fugit laboriosam enim corporis beatae sunt, quo ex blanditiis, iusto voluptate quos? Vitae, ad quas distinctio asperiores quaerat atque?
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur nam officia, fugit laboriosam enim corporis beatae sunt, quo ex blanditiis, iusto voluptate quos? Vitae, ad quas distinctio asperiores quaerat atque?
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur nam officia, fugit laboriosam enim corporis beatae sunt, quo ex blanditiis, iusto voluptate quos? Vitae, ad quas distinctio asperiores quaerat atque?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```